# selecting a colour theme in the .emacs configuration

Tags: emacs

GNU Emacs 23.1.1
    Fedora 13

I can select the colour theme by

`M-x color-theme-select`

I scroll down and select the

`clarity and beauty`

This works ok. However, in my configuration I am not sure how to select this. This is what I have, but doesn't work.

```
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-ClarityandBeauty)
```

many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`M-x color-theme-cl<Tab>` shows me that the name is `color-theme-clarity`, which means you should have this in your .emacs:

```
(color-theme-clarity)
```

Comment: Hello, I needed to add this line before color-theme-clarity. (color-theme-initialize). Thanks. Problem solved.

Answer (score 6):

This is the configuration I have (from the `color-theme` [documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/#sec8)):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/opt/elisp/color-theme") ;; The path to color-theme.el
(require 'color-theme)
(eval-after-load "color-theme"
  '(progn
     (color-theme-initialize)
     (color-theme-subtle-hacker)))  ;; This is the theme you want to use.
```